# How to connect from a linux server with php to a database that is in a windows server?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, windows

How to connect from a linux server with php to a database that is in a windows server? I have been using mysqli and stored procedures, but it doesn't work. By the way, I'm using mysql.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: In this case: $link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); it only return "Error" and just that.

Answer (score 4):

Where the database is doesn't matter for connecting. As long as you use the correct credentials and functions, it will connect.

If you see any connection method( PDO, mysqli etc ), it doesn't show the operating system anywhere. Database is running on top of the operating system.

check for errors in each step. Example:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php.

Comment: By credentials you mean : mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

Comment: yes. if all these parameter are ok, the connection doesn't care of the operating system.

Comment: But I'm doing that correctly. Because I know the credentials of my windows server. I'm typing the correct IP, user, password, and the database, and when I try to connect, it stays loading for a long time and it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what it takes so long to connect.

Comment: maybe your database service is down or not accessible through the network

Comment: Yes, it is working correctly because people at my work are using it.

Comment: It gives me an error with that : mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

Comment: Do I have to download a client or something in my linux server?

Comment: try connecting with a mysql client( like toad ) to the database

Comment: All this is correct. The problem was that the port where I had to connect, was blocked. That was the whole problem. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the Windows credentials in the MySQL call.

You need to use the MySQL credentials, since you are connecting to the database, not Windows.